# Error: The description for Event ID 4 from source PHP-7.4.1 cannot be found window & Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_sqlite'

Tags: php, wordpress, xampp

I have Xampp installed on Windows. I set a web page  with Wordpress that refreshed automatically each few minutes. 
This is all the task this computer have.

The page stack from time to time and I need to refresh it page by hand.

I checked the event log and I saw the error:

> The description for Event ID 4 from source PHP-7.4.1 cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local computer.

when I saw the details I saw:

> PHP warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
> 'pdo_sqlite'(tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\pdo_sqlite (The specified module
> could not be found.) 
>  C:\xampp\php\ext\php_pdo_sqlite.dll (The
> specificed module could not be found)) 
> (C:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe
> -d C:\xampp\apache)

The file C:\xampp\php\ext\php_pdo_sqlite.dll exist
In the file php.ini the extension_dir set to "C:\xampp\php\ext"

I use MySQL for this web page. I dont know if I need the sqlite at all.

How can I fix the problem?